# Cannot break running process in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

This has been killing me for a while. In macOS terminal, I cannot break a process. I've tried every combination of keys. <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> doesn't work.

For example, if I open a `screen` session with a serial device. It works fine but I cannot exit `screen`. The only way to kill it is by using Activity Monitor.

`stty-a` shows that most things are bound to  <kbd>^</kbd> "key", but this <kbd>Control</kbd> + "key" doesn't do anything either.

Comment: I suppose you tried cntrl-C?

Answer (score 7):

To exit `screen` you press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>.

You can find a comprehensive list of all the default key bindings in the man page ([`man screen`](https://ss64.com/osx/screen.html)).

Comment: That still doesn't work. `Conrtol + a` highlights everything in terminal, `Ctrl + Shift + a` brings me to the top of where `sceen` was started, but doesn't stop it. and Is there anything else I could be missing?

Comment: Have you remapped keybindings?  I have tested on 3 different versions of macOS and *none* will highlight everything when you press `Ctrl-A` in Terminal.  Also, it's supposed to be in `screen` that you press `Ctrl-A`.

Comment: I am not familiar with the screen command.  I noticed that command + a highlights everything.  control + a after the command + a gets rid of the highlighting.

Comment: You keep saying `Command`.  It's ***`Control`***.  It's the key directly to the right of `fn` and directly to the left of `Option`  which is to the left of `Command`.(And yes, `Command-A` does select everything; you're hitting the wrong key!)

Answer (score -2):

I found control + a d existd from the screen command.  see man screen

R

Comment: `Control-A, d` *detaches* the current screen meaning your process continues to run in `screen`.  The same but with a capital `D` detaches and logs out.  Quit is `Control-A, Control-\ ` per the [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/screen.html)